# SwiftUI: Redraw after passing dynamic data to content view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have something like below, except I have additional dynamic gestures within "ChildContentView."

How would I force a child view to redraw/reload?  Currently, any dynamic content draws once and does not reload.  All content is essentially static.

Update:
Needed to use `let content: () -> Content` instead of `@State var content: () -> Content`.

```
// ChildContentView
struct ChildContentView<Content: View>: View {
    @State var content: () -> Content

    var body: some View {
        let dragGesture = DragGesture()...

        return Group {
            self.content()
        }.gesture(dragGesture)
    }
}
```

```
// ContentView
...
@State var changingList: [FooItem] = [] <-- This is dynamically changed.  Not reflected in this code snippet.

var body: some View {
    ZStack { 
        ChildContentView {
            List(changingList) { item in
                print("\(item)")
            }
        }
    }
}
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am one month in to SwiftUI, so I don't fully understand why this works.  However, setting the variable as a constant "let" passes the view content directly with updates.

Change from:

```
struct ChildContentView<Content: View>: View {
    @State var content: () -> Content

    var body: some View {
        let dragGesture = DragGesture()...

        return Group {
            self.content()
        }.gesture(dragGesture)
    }
}
```

to this:

```
struct ChildContentView<Content: View>: View {
    let content: () -> Content

    var body: some View {
        let dragGesture = DragGesture()...

        return Group {
            self.content()
        }.gesture(dragGesture)
    }
}
```

Comment: The content does not update if using a non-state var.  Only seems to work with let.

Answer (score 1):

Your trouble is the State property wrapper

```
struct ChildContentView<Content: View>: View {

@State var content: () -> Content

    var body: some View {
        let dragGesture = DragGesture()...

        return Group {
            self.content()
        }.gesture(dragGesture)
    }
}
```

It makes the content "static" (actually you did it :-))

Let see and try this example (copy - paste - run in your simulator)

```
import SwiftUI
struct Child<Content: View>: View {
    var content: () -> Content
    var body: some View {
        content()
    }
}

struct Item: Identifiable {
    let txt: String
    let id = UUID()
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var items = [Item(txt: "Alfa"), Item(txt: "Beta")]
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Child {
                List(self.items) { (item) in
                    Text(item.txt)
                }
            }
            Button(action: {
                self.items.append(contentsOf: [Item(txt: "game"), Item(txt: "Delta")])
            }) {
                Text("Tap me to change items").padding().padding(.vertical, 50).background(Color.yellow)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I actually do have a conforming identifiable and the view updates properly.  The issue was resolved by replacing "@State var" with "let."  I am trying to figure out why this works.

Comment: You have to remove State property wrapper. If you use var or let, doesn't matter. var is required if you wrapped it with same property wrapper (Published, State, Binding, ObservedObject and EnvironmentObject are all directly supported in SwiftUI)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that an item in the list modifies it's `id` value when the content changes. Essentially hash the visual content to create a unique value per visual state.

e.g

```
struct FooItem: Identifiable {
  var id: UUID = UUID()
  var text: String = ""

  var visualID: String {
    return id.uuidString
      + "\(text.hashValue)"
  }

}
```

Im guessing that the internal `ZStack` caching doesn't recognise that the object has changed when the `id` doesn't change.

So using a `ForEach` as that's what I've got in my code ( but `List` has `id` also )...

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      ForEach(self.changingList, id: \.visualID) { item in
        SomeView(item: item)
          .onTapGesture {
            //blah blah
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I beat my head on this exact issue for days until working it out.

Comment: Already have FooItem identifiable with proper IDs.  Thanks for the response anyway.

Comment: Are your id’s mutating with the data content? Until they do your view won’t get marked for redraw.

Comment: Yes.  In fact, the list draws/redraws fine outside of "ChildContentView," but for some reason the change is not detected within "ChildContentView".